# How to find variables in an equation using javascript

Tags: javascript, formula

I want to allow users to input a mathematical equation. The equations will be simple but there will be some unknown variables.

Example 1:
`x + y - 10` here we have `x` and `y` unknown.

Example 2:
`(a + b) * (c + d)` here we have `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` unknown.

Note that the user can input n number of variables in the equation.

Now, I want to find those unknown variables from the equation. And later I will prompt the user to provide the values for those unknown variables.

Comment: This is a simple algebra, you have two variables and one equation, how would you do that?

Comment: Actually, I have to take input from the user for those variables. So that I can solve the equation and return a value. That's why I need to extract unknown variables.

Comment: ok , can't you use simple function to return the result, for your use case :- function evaluate(a, b) {
    return a + b - 1
}

Comment: variables are not just two and the number of variables is not also limited. Users can input a formula that has n number of variables.

Comment: That's a more convoluted requirement, please elaborate this here so that community can understand your requirement in detail. what can a equation be etc.

Comment: Hi, @ManishSoni I have edited my question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Math.js provides an [Expression Tree API](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/expression_trees.html#expression-trees) where you can filter the expression using `math.parse(expr)` and return the 'unknowns' you are looking for:

```js
let expr1 = 'x + y - 10'
let expr2 = '(a + b) * (c + d)'

const node1 = math.parse(expr1).filter(node => node.isSymbolNode)
const node2 = math.parse(expr2).filter(node => node.isSymbolNode)

var result1 = [...new Set(node1.map(item => item.name))]
var result2 = [...new Set(node2.map(item => item.name))]

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/9.4.4/math.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It fails for functions like sin() and cos()

Answer (score 1):

The Math.js library does not have support equations and only supports one-sided expressions. So you would not be able to solve for x using Math.js. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514302/javascript-equation-solver-library) for equation solving libraries.